How to use chatinterface and flagging at the same time?
Chatinterface and flagging cannot be working at the same time. I know this is because chatinterface does not have flagging as a parameter.
In order to use several functions, I need to definitely use chatinterface.
How can I use Flagging to get message and history of chatinterface???
Like, I would like to use flagging in this sample.
import gradio as gr

def yes_man(message, history):
    if message.endswith("?"):
        return "Yes"
    else:
        return "Ask me anything!"

gr.ChatInterface(
    yes_man,
    chatbot=gr.Chatbot(height=300),
    textbox=gr.Textbox(placeholder="Ask me a yes or no question", container=False, scale=7),
    title="Yes Man",
    description="Ask Yes Man any question",
    theme="soft",
    examples=["Hello", "Am I cool?", "Are tomatoes vegetables?"],
    cache_examples=True,
    retry_btn=None,
    undo_btn="Delete Previous",
    clear_btn="Clear",
).launch()

I was thinking of using both chatinterface and interface by trigger event or something. But did not work, in my way.
